# Constraint animations will only move up, won't move down

Tags: ios, swift, animation, autolayout

I have two buttons that trigger animations on two objects — a view and an imageView — whose positioning is set by auto layout. (While trying to problem solve this I simplified the destinations to be the top and bottom of the screen.):

```
@objc func upButtonTapped() {
    self.logo.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    self.inputsView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    print("Up")
}
@objc func downButtonTapped() {
    self.logo.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    self.inputsView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    print("Down")
}
```

The upButtonTapped animations work fine but downButtonTapped's don't. After playing with the destinations for way too long I realized no combination of anchor points and constraints will cause the objects to animate down the screen. Both functions are targeted by their respective buttons correctly, and I've tried swapping the constraint updates between each to the same results.

In case it helps, here's the initial constraints I set for the two objects (using a custom extension):

```
logo.anchor(xCenter: view.centerXAnchor,
            yCenter: view.topAnchor, yCenterConstant: view.frame.height / 3,
            width: 65)
inputsView.anchor(bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, bottomConstant: -100,
                  xCenter: view.centerXAnchor,
                  width: view.frame.width * 0.7,
                  height: 200)
```

Can anyone tell me at all what's going on/how to fix?

Comment: You're over constraining your views.  You need to keep track of the earlier constraints and deactivate the constraints that establish the vertical position of the views before setting new vertical constraints.

Comment: @vacawama If I set both of the buttons to move the views up the screen the animations work fine and I can continue calling them without issue. It's only when I try to animate them toward the bottom of the screen that they don't function

Comment: @vacawama I did an additional test and added a horizontal move to the animations and the same things occurs — animating the view to the left works fine, but they won't move to the right. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your result with a single view.  You problem is that your view is over constrained because you keep adding new constraints, but you never remove them.  When a view is overconstrained, *Auto Layout* breaks the constraints by choosing which ones to leave out.  For whatever reason, it is favoring the "up" constraints.  You need to have a property that keeps track of the vertical constraint, and you need to set `isActive = false` on that constraint before creating and activating the new one.

Here is the code for my example.  I am moving a single red square view to the top and bottom of the screen.  Notice how I use a property to keep track of the constraint that positions the view in the vertical direction and how I use that property to deactivate the current constraint and then store and active the new one.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var redView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var redCenter: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var redCenterConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // start with the constraint set in the Storyboard
        redCenterConstraint = redCenter
    }

    @IBAction func moveUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // deactivate the current constraint
        redCenterConstraint?.isActive = false

        // create the new constraint
        redCenterConstraint = redView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0)

        // activate the new constraint
        redCenterConstraint?.isActive = true

        // animate the change
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func moveDown(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // deactivate the current constraint
        redCenterConstraint?.isActive = false

        // create the new constraint
        redCenterConstraint = redView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)

        // activate the new constraint
        redCenterConstraint?.isActive = true

        // animate the change
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here it is running in the simulator:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try below code I just add completion handler:---

```
func downAnimation() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.4, delay: 0.0, options: [],animations: {
        self.logo.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        self.inputsView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:    self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }) { (complete) in

        if self.isAnimate{
            self.upAnimation()
        }
    }
}

func upAnimation() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.4, delay: 0.0, options: [],animations: {
        self.logo.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        self.inputsView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }) { (complete) in
        if self.isAnimate {
            self.downAnimation()
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you,
Thank you.